# How to control/scale image size in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I used the (new) GUI Builder and inserted an image (by way of adding a Label). However, it appears too big. Is there anyway I can scale and control the size? (I saw something which points to cloudinary but that seems too complicated. I just want to simply scale down the image.)

Comment: I poked around the GUI Builder but could not find any way to control the image size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to resize images in Codename One and I will mention few below:

## 1.

Use MultiImages in the GUI Builder. With this multiple sizes of images are generated from one image based on the sizes you specified. In your GUI Builder, Click Images -> Add Multi Images -> Select your image -> Check `Preserve Aspect Ratio` -> Increase the % that represents the percentage of the screen width you want the image to occupy. Set any DPI you don't require to 0.

## 2.

Use ScaledImageLabel or ScaledImageButton, it will resize the image the fill available space the component is occupying.

## 3.

Scale the image itself in code *(This is not efficient, though)*:

```
public static Image getImageFromTheme(String name) {
    try {
        Resources resFile = Resources.openLayered("/theme");
        Image image = resFile.getImage(name);
        return image;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //Log.p("Image " + name + " not found: " + ioe);
    }
    return null;
}

Image resizedImage = getImageFromTheme("myImage").scaledWidth(Math.round(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 10)); //change value as necessary
```

## 4.

Mutate the image (Create an image from another image).

Comment: I used ScaledImageLabel and it did reduced the image. The image is smaller than the original. HOWEVER, it still did NOT reduce it enough to fit in the visual area (ie. the displayed image, though it is reduced but not enough and therefore it is still cropped when displayed) The code is in the show() method here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871223/how-do-i-hide-get-rid-the-title-bar-on-a-form-codename-one]

Comment: What does the image look like? Mind editing your question to add a screenshot?

Comment: You might be looking for "scale to fit" which you can toggle in that component. I think it defaults to "scale to fill"