# How do I hide/get rid the title bar on a Form? Codename One

Tags: codenameone

How do I hide/get rid the title bar on a Form?

I tried to do that by created a custom class of Form and override shouldPaintStatusBar() but it didn't work.

The entire code is:

```
public class SplashScreenOp {
    private Resources theme;
    private Form splashForm;
    public Form getForm() {
        return splashForm;
    }

    public SplashScreenOp(Resources theme) {
        super();
        this.theme = theme;
    }

    public final void show() {
        splashForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
        Image splashScreenImage = theme.getImage("splashscreen.png");
        ScaleImageLabel scaleImageLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(splashScreenImage);
        splashForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scaleImageLabel);
        splashForm.show();
    }
}
```

As this is a splash page, so only the image should be displayed. ie. No title bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are using `Toolbar` globally. You can hide title bar by not adding any `TitleCommand` and by calling either of below (or both):

```
splashForm.getToolbar().setUIID("Container");
```

:

```
splashForm.getToolbar().hideToolbar();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! (I had to call BOTH in order to make it work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call:

```
splashForm.removeComponent(splashForm.getTitleComponent());
```